# How to draw points in x/y positions using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to plot points in two dimensional fashion (each have an x and y coordinates). I was wondering if you know of a library or project that does this so that I don't have to build this from scratch.

Comment: Do you need axis too? To give the points context?

Comment: Yes...actually I need to show more like a square divided into four quadrants in addition to the axis

Comment: Are you using `<canvas>` or SVG?

Comment: I believe SVG as I'm not using HTML5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have one:

https://github.com/sameerb/jsDraw2D

Edit:
I've updated the link I had posted before

Answer (score 15):

Using the canvas tag is the best way of doing this. Here is an example that creates a Canvas:

```js
// Create a canvas that extends the entire screen
// and it will draw right over the other html elements, like buttons, etc
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.setAttribute("width", window.innerWidth);
canvas.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight);
canvas.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; x:0; y:0;");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

//Then you can draw a point at (10,10) like this:

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(10,10,1,1);
```

Furthermore, you can manipulate all the pixels on the screen using ImageData.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes

Comment: The rectangle is easier to find if it's a little larger you might try  `ctx.fillRect(10,10,10,10); `

Answer (score 2):

[Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) - a small JavaScript library that should simplify your work with vector graphics on the web.

Answer (score 2):

If you've using jQuery already, then [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is a very very simple (but powerful) way to draw graphs.

You could also look at the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) -- guaranteed cross-browser: it gives you a graph as an image, instead of canvas or VML, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most simple way:

```
point(30,30)
```

this JavaScript code uses [p5js](https://p5js.org/), full example:

html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px;">
    <main>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

sketch.js:

```
function preload() {
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke('white'); 
  strokeWeight(10);
  point(window.innerWidth/2,window.innerHeight/2);
}
```

More complex article about it:
http://en.jkeks.ru/javascript-how-to-draw-a-point-on-the-screen/

Answer (score 0):

I think this one hits the nail on the head for you:

http://www.jsclasses.org/package/332-JavaScript-Calculate-coordinates-of-lines-curves-and-shapes.html

returns values in x and y array for easy use in graphics and movement